# Spring Securities Test Cannot Find Bean Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

I am using the following codes to test rest controller with Spring securities. WebMvcTest is been used to perform test. I do not want to use SpringBootTest annotation as it will make the testing very slow to start the entire application context.

```
package org.project.rest;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.project.model.SampleBean;
import org.project.service.SampleBeanService;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) // tells JUnit to run using Spring’s testing support.
@WebMvcTest(SampleBeanRestController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SampleBeanRestControllerTest  {

   @MockBean
   private SampleBeanService SampleBeanService;

   @Autowired
   private MockMvc mockMvc;

   public MockMvc getMockMvc() {
      return mockMvc;
   }

   @Test
   @WithMockUser(username = "user", password = "password", roles = "USER")
   public void deleteSampleById() throws Exception{
      getMockMvc().perform(delete("/api/sample/1")
         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
         .andExpect(status().isOk());
   }

}
```

And I get the following error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in org.project.config.WebSecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.project.security.jwt.TokenProvider' that could not be found.
```

How can I bypass this? TokenProvider has been imported in the WebSecurityConfig. Thanks.

Comment: can you show the test class code ?

Comment: @Deadpool. I have made an update. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, a `@WebMvcTest` test focuses only on Spring MVC components.

You have a missing bean definition in your `@WebMvcTest` context. Because you don't use `@SpringBootTest` all the components which are not related to Spring MVC context ignored (like `@Component`, `@Service` or `@Repository` beans).

Therefore, you need to add your `TokenProvider` component additionally, and if you have any other beans also which depend on MVC:

```java
@TestConfiguration
public class SampleBeanRestControllerTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public TokenProvider tokenProvider() {
        return new TokenProvider();
    }

}
```

Next, import your test config:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(SampleBeanRestControllerTestConfig.class)
@WebMvcTest(SampleBeanRestController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SampleBeanRestControllerTest  {

   //...

}
```

That should work unless the `TokenProvider` has other dependencies. If so you need to create them also as `@Bean`s. Alternatively, you can consider using `@MockBean` or mocking them manually if it makes sense.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Hi Yavusz, thanks for your reply. I fixed this one, then it comes out more missing beans. How can I keep all the files for Spring securities?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to do that in short. The beans that depend on and their transitive ones should be defined or mocked one by one. Or if it looks like to cover almost all beans, consider using `@SpringBootTest`. However, if this is the case this can be a sign of bad design and misuse of dependency injection in terms of Single Reponsibility Principle.

Comment: It turns out to have 4 beans to defined. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helped you!